# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when ending scene in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a usual iOS Cocos2d game. I start with a MainMenuViewController, which then pushes my rootViewController when the "new game" button is pressed, which then sets up the cocos2d scene and the HelloWorldLayer. Im not sure if any of that relevant.

The problem is when I want to end my game. When the player has 0 lives left and a certain collison is detected, I want the scene to end, and I want to pop back to my main menu. So I call the following method from within my `update: (ccTime) dt` method immediately after collision is detected:

```
-(void)endScene {
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopBackgroundMusic];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
    [_rootViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The problem is that when ending the scene, I get a variety of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors. The one I get most often is in CCScheduler.m:

```
// delete all updates that are marked for deletion
// updates with priority < 0
DL_FOREACH_SAFE( updatesNeg, entry, tmp ) {
    if(entry->markedForDeletion )
    {
        [self removeUpdateFromHash:entry]; //THIS IS WHERE IS GET EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    }
}
```

The only thing logged by Cocos2d is

```
2012-03-02 13:36:20.849 Psycho Circles[25265:707] cocos2d: deallocing <CCScheduler: 0x3a3330>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];`

Is not what you call to end a scene.

Look at this example for how to switch scenes:

http://ganbarugames.com/2010/12/understanding-scenes-in-cocos2d-iphone/

```
CCTransitionRotoZoom *transition = [CCTransitionRotoZoom transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[HelloWorld scene]];
// Tell the director to run the transition
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transition];
```

Comment: That link seems to assume the previous screen is also a Cocos2s scene. My problem is I only have 1 scene, and then I want to be done with Cocos2d, then pop back to my first ViewController, which does not use Cocos2d and is just a normal UIKit nib. So I dont see why replacing a scene would help.

Comment: OK Ive got it - I just stop the selectors and pop the view when Im done, and then when I go back into the game I replace the scene instead of restarting. Seems to work.

Comment: Ah, ok. You're right that the example is for switching between scenes. I mis-interpreted your question because I assumed the menu was another scene, as it was when I wrote my iPhone game. :)